# My ubuntu can't kill the process which occupy too much memory?

Tags: c

When I tested it, my computer tried it best to provide the most memory to my program.. And my computer crashed.. But I remembered that ubuntu will kill this process if it needs too much memory continually.. Why it becomes this?

```
/*I write the code to test how much memory can my computer provide the most*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int m = 0 ;
    while( malloc(1 << 20) )
    {
        printf ("%d MB\n", ++m) ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: But here you are just continually requesting memory until no more can be given, but you are not saving the pointers. This is pretty much the definition of a memory leek. Perhaps this happens too fast for ubuntu too react as you are doing nothing but requesting all the memory in small blocks! Why don't you use `top` to check the memory usage without requesting it?

Comment: Define "crash".  And since you are only allocating the memory, but never touching it, your program isn't actually consuming any memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the memory isn't allocated but only reserved, this will fill up some other parts of the system like the page table but not the physical memory which the *Out of memory killer* handles. Try using memset() on your memory block before leaking it.

You might also be interested in looking up about /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory

From: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

> overcommit_memory:
>
> This value contains a flag that enables memory overcommitment.
>
> When this flag is 0, the kernel attempts to estimate the amount of
>   free memory left when userspace requests more memory.
>
> When this flag is 1, the kernel pretends there is always enough memory
>   until it actually runs out.
>
> When this flag is 2, the kernel uses a "never overcommit" policy that
>   attempts to prevent any overcommit of memory. Note that
>   user_reserve_kbytes affects this policy.
>
> This feature can be very useful because there are a lot of programs
>   that malloc() huge amounts of memory "just-in-case" and don't use much
>   of it.
>
> The default value is 0.